# Summing of even binomial coefficients with parity

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a general formula for
$$
\sum_{2m\le n}(-1)^m\left( n\atop 2m\right)
$$
where $n$ could be either even or odd?

**EDIT**. Just realized that this is equal to $\Re(1+i)^n$.

Comment: See [OEIS A009116](https://oeis.org/A009116).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your edit is correct; equivalently, it's

$$\frac{(1 + i)^n + (1 - i)^n}{2}.$$

When $n$ is even we have $(1 \pm i)^2 = \pm 2i$ so this simplifies to

$$\frac{(2i)^{\frac{n}{2}} + (-2i)^{\frac{n}{2}}}{2}$$

which is $0$ if $n \equiv 2 \bmod 4$ and $(-4)^{\frac{n}{4}}$ if $n \equiv 0 \bmod 4$. (This kind of periodicity is to be expected because $1 + i$ is a real multiple of an $8^{th}$ root of unity.) When $n$ is odd we instead get

$$\frac{(1 + i)(2i)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} + (1 - i)(-2i)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}}{2}$$

which is $(-4)^{\frac{n-1}{4}}$ if $n \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and, if I haven't made a mistake, $(-2)(-4)^{\frac{n-3}{4}}$ if $n \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.

Plausibly a nicer and less error-prone way to organize this computation is to write $1 + i = \sqrt{2} \zeta_8$ where $\zeta_8 = e^{ \frac{\pi i}{4} }$ is a primitive $8^{th}$ root of unity, which gives

$$\text{Re}((1 + i)^n) = 2^{\frac{n}{2}} \cos \frac{n \pi}{4}.$$